# android MediaPlayer error -2147483648

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, surfaceview, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to use live streaming in my application. To do that, I've used MediaPlayer to play the video, SurfaceView to display the video and HLS protocol. It is working well, but on some devices, I've received some problems which the most important one is:

```
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

I've searched a lot about this problem (here in StackOverflow site and the others) but found no appropriate solution. according to [this site](https://docs.brightcove.com/en/player/mobile-sdks/hls-player/guides/hls-limitations.html#Known%20limitations) the HLS protocol is supported by android since API 16 as well, but that problem is reported on devices with API greater than 16. My major question is:

- why this problem occurs? (Consider I'm using live streaming in HLS protocol, not local file)

Comment: I don't know what this means, but that error looks like an underflown integer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate not at all, it's a negative error code (`UNKNOWN_ERROR = 0x80000000`)

Comment: @javaDroid HLS may be supported, but not all codec profiles work across all devices. Check the encoding parameters and compare with the [supported media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html).

Comment: Finally, I've found my solution. my video at the server has codecs which are not supported by android. By changing that errors my problem was fixed.